# Android programmatically complete the process

Tags: android, kill-process

Is it possible in the android to programmatically complete the process of a third-party application . I've seen several applications that let you do this.

Comment: You mean shut down the process of an ongoing app?

Comment: No, I need to complete the process of a third-party application.

Comment: Not sure what that means...

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "complete the process" means to you, as that phrase has no specific meaning in computer programming.

Comment: Stop, or kill, or close. Do everything possible so that the program is gone from the foreground.